# Vuejs html checkbox check state not updated correctly

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, checkbox

Having issues getting some checkboxes to work properly. So in my component I have an array of objects set in a state variable `tokenPermissions` that look like this

```
tokenPermissions: [
        {
          groupName: "App",
          allSelected: false,
          someSelected: false,
          summary: "Full access to all project operations",
          permissions: [
            {
              name: "can_create_app",
              summary: "Create new projects",
              selected: false,
            },
            {
              name: "can_delete_app",
              summary: "Delete existing projects",
              selected: false,
            },
            {
              name: "can_edit_app",
              summary: "Edit an existing project",
              selected: false,
            },
          ],
        }
      ],
```

The goal is to loop through this array and have a parent and children checkboxes like so `tokenPermissions[i].allSelected` bound to the parent checkbox and for each object in `tokenPermissions[i].permissions` a corresponding checkbox bound to the `selected` property like so `tokenPermissions[i].permissions[j].selected`.

Desired behaviour when the parent checkbox is selected,

1. If all child checkboxes checked, uncheck all, including the parent
2. If child checkboxes are unchecked check all including the parent
3. if only some of the child checkboxes are selected, the parent would show the indeterminate `-` icon or sign and on click, uncheck all child checkboxes including the parent.

The issue is point 3. The issue is sometimes the parent checkbox is not correctly checked based on the state of the attribute bounded to. For example `allSelected` can be `false` but the parent checkbox is checked.

I put a complete working example on github here https://github.com/oaks-view/vuejs-checkbox-issue.

The bit of code with the binding is as follows

```
<ul
      class="list-group"
      v-for="(permissionGroup, permissionGroupIndex) in tokenPermissions"
      :key="`${permissionGroup.groupName}_${permissionGroupIndex}`"
    >
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="permission-container">
          <div>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              :indeterminate.prop="
                !permissionGroup.allSelected && permissionGroup.someSelected
              "
              v-model="permissionGroup.allSelected"
              :id="permissionGroup.groupName"
              v-on:change="
                permissionGroupCheckboxChanged($event, permissionGroupIndex)
              "
            />
            <label :for="permissionGroup.groupName" class="cursor-pointer"
              >{{ permissionGroup.groupName }} -
              <span style="color: red; margin-left: 14px; padding-right: 3px">{{
                permissionGroup.allSelected
              }}</span></label
            >
          </div>
          <div class="permission-summary">
            {{ permissionGroup.summary }}
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li
            class="list-group-item list-group-item-no-margin"
            v-for="(permission, permissionIndex) in permissionGroup.permissions"
            :key="`${permissionGroup.groupName}_${permission.name}_${permissionIndex}`"
          >
            <div class="permission-container">
              <div>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  :id="permission.name"
                  v-bind:checked="permission.selected"
                  v-on:change="
                    permissionGroupCheckboxChanged(
                      $event,
                      permissionGroupIndex,
                      permissionIndex
                    )
                  "
                />
                <label :for="permission.name" class="cursor-pointer"
                  >{{ permission.name
                  }}<span
                    style="color: red; margin-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px"
                    >&nbsp; {{ permission.selected }}</span
                  ></label
                >
              </div>
              <div class="permission-summary">
                {{ permission.summary }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

And for updating the checkbox

```
    getPermissionGroupSelectionStatus: function (permissionGroup) {
      let allSelected = true;
      let someSelected = false;

      permissionGroup.permissions.forEach((permission) => {
        if (permission.selected === false) {
          allSelected = false;
        }
        if (permission.selected === true) {
          someSelected = true;
        }
      });

      return { allSelected, someSelected };
    },
    permissionGroupCheckboxChanged: function (
      $event,
      permissionGroupIndex,
      permissionIndex
    ) {
      const { checked } = $event.target;

      // its single permission selected
      if (permissionIndex !== undefined) {
        this.tokenPermissions[permissionGroupIndex].permissions[
          permissionIndex
        ].selected = checked;

        const { allSelected, someSelected } =
          this.getPermissionGroupSelectionStatus(
            this.tokenPermissions[permissionGroupIndex]
          );

        this.tokenPermissions[permissionGroupIndex].allSelected = allSelected;
        this.tokenPermissions[permissionGroupIndex].someSelected = someSelected;
      } else {
        // its selectAll check box
        const { allSelected, someSelected } =
          this.getPermissionGroupSelectionStatus(
            this.tokenPermissions[permissionGroupIndex]
          );

        let checkAll;

        // no checkbox / permission is selected then set all
        if (!someSelected && !allSelected) {
          checkAll = true;
        } else {
          checkAll = false;
        }

        this.tokenPermissions[permissionGroupIndex].allSelected = checkAll;
        this.tokenPermissions[permissionGroupIndex].someSelected = checkAll;

        for (
          let i = 0;
          i < this.tokenPermissions[permissionGroupIndex].permissions.length;
          i++
        ) {
          this.tokenPermissions[permissionGroupIndex].permissions[i].selected =
            checkAll;
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a rendering problem.
Vue set the `allSelected` checkbox as checked, then in the same cycle updates it to false; you can read about Vue life cycle here: https://it.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

A pretty brutal (but simple) way to resolve it (which I don't recommend, but it's useful to understand what's happening) is to delay the update.

Wrap the last part of the method `permissionGroupCheckboxChanged` with a `this.$nextTick`:

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.tokenPermissions[permissionGroupIndex].allSelected = checkAll;
      this.tokenPermissions[permissionGroupIndex].someSelected = checkAll;

      for (
        let i = 0;
        i < this.tokenPermissions[permissionGroupIndex].permissions.length;
        i++
      ) {
        this.tokenPermissions[permissionGroupIndex].permissions[i].selected =
          checkAll;
      }
    })
```

This way when you change the values, the engine reacts accordingly.
Still I don't recommend it (I think `nextTick` is useful to understand the Vue life cycle, but I would recommend against using it whenever is possible).

---

A less brutal (and simpler) way is to set the `allSelected` to `null` instead of `false` when `checkAll` is not true `permissionGroupCheckboxChanged`:

```
// this
this.tokenPermissions[permissionGroupIndex].allSelected = checkAll ? checkAll : null;

// instead of this
this.tokenPermissions[permissionGroupIndex].allSelected = checkAll;
```

this way the prop wins against the model (as the model value becomes `null`).

---

But the even better option (imho) would be to use a component of its own inside the `v-for` loop and have `allSelected` and `someSelected` as computed properties instead of values bound to real variables.
Usually you should not store ui status as data when it can be inferred from real data (I may be wrong, as I don't know your application, but in your case I suspect you are interested in the single checkboxes' values, while `allSelected`/`someSelected` are merely used for ui).